# Find lines in image with endpoints using GPUImage

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision, gpuimage

I'm pretty new to computer vision, but I'm trying to basically find all the straight lines in a hand drawn image as seen by the camera. I'm using the GPUImage library by Brad Larson, and I'm able to find the lines using a Hough Transform, but this gives me slopes and intercepts. Is there a way to get the endpoints? It's not really possible to determine the lengths via intersections due to the nature of the images. I've started looking into the full OpenCV library, but that seems considerably more complicated.

Comment: try HoughLinesP function, which will compute end points. Or try LineSegmentDetector and some logic to compute the end points or lines.